# How to test simple sum method in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-test

I'm literally amateur when it comes to testing in Angular 5.

This is my simple Component:

```
interface TotalAmount {
  alphaAmount: number;
  betaAmount: number;
}

export class TransactionSummaryComponent implements OnInit {

  private id = 1;
  transactionSummary: TransactionSummary;
  totalAmount: TotalAmount;

  constructor(private payService: PayService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadTransactionSummary();
  }

  loadTransactionSummary(): void {
    this.payService.getTransactionSummary(this.id).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data !== null) {
          this.transactionSummary = data;
          this.calculateTotalAmount();
        }
      }
    );
  }

  calculateTotalAmount(): void {
    this.totalAmount = {
      alphaAmount: this.transactionSummary.alphaAmountNew + this.transactionSummary.alphaAmountOld,
      betaAmount: this.transactionSummary.betaAmountNew + this.transactionSummary.betaAmountOld
    };
  }
}
```

As you can see it's really simple. I'm loading data using http service `loadTransactionSummary()` then I run method `calculateTotalAmount()` which sum received data.

I wondering how should I test this `calculateTotalAmount()` method. Since there is some business logic so should be tested. Right? Should I really make the http request to get `transactionSummary` data or maybe I should mock those data somehow? What is the best approach in such a case? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Yes, you should absolutely mock the data. Read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/testing.

Comment: Did you read through the awesome tutorial about testing that the Angular team has in their docs? I think they should be a great help and show you exactly how to do that. https://angular.io/guide/testing